# ow to use different code for each language

Tags: php, wordpress, multilingual, contacts

We are using WordPress with WPML plugin for 3 different languages. On the product page, we have inserted a custom PHP for calling a Contact Form 7 contact form:

The problem is that the contact form is ALWAYS in one language. How is the best way to either select a new form for each language or translate the strings in the contact form 7?

The default language is just domainname.dk - and in english f.eks. domainname.dk/en

Can I somehow look up if the domain starts with domainname.dk/en - then....?

Comment: https://contactform7.com/contact-form-in-your-language/

Answer (score 0):

I found this code that works:

if ($lang == 'en-US') : 
echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="9479" title="offer"]' );